# Create a trigger that updates a column in a table when a different column in the same table is updated - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

How to create a trigger that updates a column in a table when a different column in the same table is updated.

So far I have done the following which works when any new data is created. Its able to copy data from "Purchase Requisition" to "PO_Number" however when data has been modified in "Purchase Requisition" , no changes is made to "PO_Number" and the value becomes NULL. Any kind help will be seriously appreciated.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PO_Number_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[TheCat2]
AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN

   UPDATE  dbo.TheCat2 SET PO_Number=(select Purchase_Requisition from inserted)  where DocNo= (Select DocNo from inserted);
   END
```

Comment: Your Trigger is not Batch safe....

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'UPDATE' as well as insert to the trigger, otherwise it will only execute on new data, not updated data. Also added 'top 1' to the select statements from the inserted table to allow this to be 'safe' on batch updates, however it will only update 1 record.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PO_Number_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[TheCat2]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS BEGIN

   UPDATE  dbo.TheCat2 SET PO_Number=(select top 1 Purchase_Requisition from inserted)  where DocNo= (Select top 1 DocNo from inserted);
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much, pretty fresh in SQL scripting and appreciate the assistance. Always happy to learn new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:
Your trigger is altering all rows in `TheCat2`.  Presumably, you only want to alter the new ones:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PO_Number_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[TheCat2] AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
   UPDATE tc
       SET PO_Number = Purchase_Requisition
       FROM dbo.TheCat2 tc JOIN
            inserted i
            on tc.DocNo = i.DocNo ;
END;
```

However, perhaps a computed column is sufficient for your purposes:

```
alter table add PO_Number as Purchase_Requisition;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. appreciate all the assistance. I'm happy I can always learn new stuff on here..